# Cleanup a dataframe using pd.apply()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe. I tried to clean it up along these lines by iterating over rows and columns. I found out that takes a long time. So I'm trying to use pd.apply(), but having trouble with the implementation.

Here was the attempt that takes forever:

````
def elim_com(x):
    try:
        x.replace(',',' ')
    except ValueError:
        return x

def to_number(x):
    try:
        x=float(x)
        return(x)
    except ValueError:
        return x

for row in range(df.shape[0]):
    for column in range(0,dfconvertendum.shape[1],1):
        try:
            dfconvertendum.iloc[row,column]=elim_com(dfconvertendum.iloc[row,column])
        except TypeError:
            continue
        except AttributeError:
            continue

for row in range(df.shape[0]):
    for column in range(0,df.shape[1],1):
        try:
            dfconvertendum.iloc[row,column]=to_number(dfconvertendum.iloc[row,column])    
        except TypeError:
            continue```

Here is my attempt using apply:

```## Clean using apply 

def elim_com(x):
    try:
        x.replace(',',' ')
    except ValueError:
        return x

def to_number(x):
    try:
        x=float(x)
        return(x)
    except ValueError:
        return x

dfconvertendum=dfconvertendum.apply(elim_com)
dfconvertendum=dfconvertendum.apply(to_num)
````

The goal is to have single df with floats where there is currently a df dtype called object. I've also tried to_numeric but it blows things up invarious ways. I'd like a light touch cleaning. I want to leave everything in tact that is not plainly a number with commas, remove the commas, and convert to a float.
Best!

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data and your expected output. Code is honestly mostly irrelevant here.

Comment: Hey! How many columns are you working with? Do you know which will be floats and in which columns you want to erase commas?

Comment: Hi Juan, I have already doctored the frame a bit - taken out nonNumeric columns so I'd like to take out all the commas in all the columns.  And once I've rid myself of the commas, then I'm trying to make 'em floats.

Comment: It would be great if you could address the comments.

Comment: @RudolftheReindeer, changed my answer based on what you just said

Comment: I'm working with 160 columns.

Comment: @coldspeed, I'm having some trouble displaying a snippet of the frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, without trying to be rude, your code is as inefficient as it gets. One of the great things about `pandas` is that you can perform vectorized operations, that are quite fast. Assuming you know which columns you want to turn into float, and in which columns you want to delete commas, you can do the following:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col]=df[col].str.replace(',','').astype(float)
```

Edit: Changed answer based on your feedback

Comment: This avoided the errors I was throwing but only converted some of the columns.   ```for col in dfconvertendum:
    try:
        dfconvertendum[col]=dfconvertendum[col].str.replace(',','').astype(float)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    except AttributeError:
        continue```

Comment: You'll have to manually identify the columns that have a type that doesn't correspond to the desired data type. If it makes it easier you can split your columns based on data type using `.isinstance()` and manually detecting which columns aren't what you want them to be

Comment: When checking dfconvertendum.dtypes, I'm still returning plenty of 'object' dtype columns. Does this mean that at least one row of that column is 'object' dtype. Or does the object dtype mean ALL rows in a column are 'object' dtype?

Comment: Sorry if I'm late, but if you only have one string value in a `float`column, it will show as `object`. Happens a lot with databases that have a whitespace instead of a missing value.

Answer (score 0):

I did it. Trick in my case was to clean up 'N/A' with np.NaN, THEN do a pd.apply. This allowed me to .sort_values() as desired.

````
df=df.replace('N/A',np.NaN)

for col in df:
    try:
        df[col]=df[col].str.replace(',','').astype(float)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    except AttributeError:
        continue
    except KeyError:
        continue```
````